# 16 bit adder into Spartan 6 (16 bit into 8 external switches)

Tags: verilog

i have designed 16 bit adder circuit in verilog. but spartan 6 board has only 8 switches in it.

so, can anyone help me in knowing how to link 16 bit adder in spartan 6 board for 8 external switches.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more resourceful, think about all the different uses for the resources on your development kit. Does it have a clock source? Maybe you could provide one with one of the eight switches, and then use another switch for data input? Have you learned about shift registers yet?

Unless you have good memory you need a way to know what the value of the shift registers are. Does your dev kit have LEDs? Or maybe a seven segment display? There's probably not enough of them, but maybe you could use the other switches to display different parts of the registers you're interested in?